# Issue RaspberryPi 3b+ and docker compose : Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a rapsberrypi 3b+, with Raspbian Buster Lite (version : February 2020)
I installed all dependencies as mentioned in this tutorial https://medium.com/@techiebouncer/install-docker-and-docker-compose-on-raspberry-pi-4-raspbian-buster-c5b78b9a0d08. Everything is up-to-date, however with I create my container there is a issue at step two of the Dockerfile when running this cmd :

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install build-essential -y \
&& pip install poetry
```

The error message is very long:

```
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; platform_python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (100 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
    Downloading setuptools-46.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (582 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
    Downloading cffi-1.14.0.tar.gz (463 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-tib_06xh
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/c
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
              ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
    Running setup.py clean for cffi
  Failed to build cffi
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycparser, cffi
      Running setup.py install for cffi: started
      Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8j22vllc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay/include/python3.7m/cffi
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/
      Complete output (36 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/c
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
      c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
       #include <ffi.h>
                ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3618jys/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8j22vllc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay/include/python3.7m/cffi Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-e8my0zvf/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; platform_python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It seems that there is an issue with *libffi-dev* module but it is up-to-date.
Or with gcc but I don't know what to install?

Comment: You have to install `libffi-dev` in the image, not on the host; `RUN apt install libffi-dev` missing.

Comment: @hoefling I have a new issue, but it has solved the first error message and that’s perfect !! just by curiosity how did you know thanks to the error message that you have to install it in the image and not in the host? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are building a docker image, every build dependency should be installed into the image, not on the host. If the package is required only for building, but not when running the image, you can uninstall it to reduce the image size:

```
RUN apt update \
  && apt install build-essential libffi-dev -y \
  && pip install poetry \
  && apt remove build-essential libffi-dev -y
```

> how did you know thanks to the error message that you have to install it in the image and not in the host?

The error message

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
       #include <ffi.h>
                ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

indicates that the `ffi.h` is not available in the image when `RUN pip install poetry` is executed - the package that provides it on Debian and derivatives is `libffi-dev`.